# Android: How to use constraint_height_percent inside a layout that will be included in a parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

Currently, I am trying to make my heights and widths of my views relative to the available space, so my ui will be more responsible. The problem I encounter is that whenever I try to include this layouts inside a parent layout (e.g include shop_content inside fragment_shop), the heights and widths of my included layout don't work anymore.

I've made a small example to show this. In this example, you can see that the height of the toolbar should take 17% of the given height. Everything works fine when I look at my design tab inside the child layout, but when importing this layout inside my fragment_shopping_cart, the view remains invisible / the height is not shown properly.

### child_layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> <!-- Changing this to wrap_content makes weird stuff -->

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.17" <!-- Height should take 0.17 -->
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### parent_layout

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".framework.ui.view.fragments.shop.ShoppingCartFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/shopping_cart_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/color_primary"
            app:title="@string/bottom_nav_shopping_cart"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_shopping_cart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/shopping_cart_btn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/shopping_cart_toolbar"
            tools:listitem="@layout/shopping_cart_list_item" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/shopping_cart_btn"
            layout="@layout/child_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### How it should look

[image]

### How it looks

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I appreciate every help. Note: I am new to responsive ui in Android

### EDIT

As this question gets harder to understand, I will try to explain it better with this example: I have a layout called **app_standard_checkout_btn** that I use in several of my layouts (including it). This layout contains different views such as a *toolbar* (serves as a background), textview and other stuff.

Currently, the height of the *toolbar* is fix with 124dp and here lies the problem. I don't want the height to be 124dp but rather to be 0.15 of the entire available height in which the layout is included in (which is same as 124dp in some cases). How is this achievable?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="price"
            type="Float" />
        <variable
            name="btnText"
            type="String" />
        <variable
            name="btnIcon"
            type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable" />
        <variable
            name="btnTextCapitalized"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="124dp" <!-- THIS FIXED VALUE IS BAD -->
            android:background="@color/color_btn_gray"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_sum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard8dpMargin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/big16dpMargin"
            android:text="@string/calibrate_btn_price"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_dark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textHeadlineNormal2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/shop_item_price"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shop_item_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{price}"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textHeadlineNormal2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_sum"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/calibbrate_btn_tv_intern_curr"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_sum"
            tools:text="4800.00" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calibbrate_btn_tv_intern_curr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/currency"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textHeadlineNormal2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/shop_item_price"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_next"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/shop_item_price" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/calibrate_btn_desc"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textDescriptionNormal4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_next"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shop_item_price" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/big16dpMargin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/big16dpMargin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standard8dpMargin"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="@{btnText}"
            android:textAllCaps="@{btnTextCapitalized}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textDescriptionNormal1"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/color_btn_blue"
            app:icon="@{btnIcon}"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/calibrate_btn_background"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/calibrate_btn_background"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_background" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Something got in my mind after posting an answer .. you need `17% of the given height` to the Toolbar .. I assume you need this from the total height of the parent layout (not the height of the child layout), there are two options you need to do this: *first* the Toolbar must be a child of the parent layout `ConstraintLayout` to constraint the 17% from it. *second:* your child layout shouldn't have any constraints to the Views in the parent layout.. in order to fill the entire area of its parent, and therefore to allow the toolbar height to be 17% of the entire height..

Comment: toolbar CANT BE a child of the parent constraintlayout, because this would make the `include` tag obsolete. If toolbar must be child of the parent layout, then how am I able to include it? Could you maybe change your answer then, applying yours doesn't fix mine. Second, the toolbar should NOT fill the entire parent, but only 0.17 of it. What is the pupose of my toolbar that fills the entire view, when the recyclerview is not shown anymore?

Comment: sure I will .. but need to understand more .. Now you need the toolbar to be 17% of the parent layout .. Do you want the child layout to have the same height/width of the parent?

Comment: @Zain I've edited my question, hope it is understandable with this.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question .. In your phrase ` in which the layout is included in` do you mean the `app_standard_checkout_btn` or the layout that reference it ?

Comment: The layout that references it. So if `fragment_shop` includes `app_standard_checkout_btn`, toolbar height should be 0.15 of `fragment_shop` height

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226835/discussion-between-zain-and-andrew).

Answer (score 1):

You need to constraint the top of the `child_layout` to the bottom of the `ReyclerView`

So add bleow constraint to the `child_layout`

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_shopping_cart"
```

Upon this change, the entire parent layout will be:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".framework.ui.view.fragments.shop.ShoppingCartFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/shopping_cart_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/color_primary"
            app:title="@string/bottom_nav_shopping_cart"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_shopping_cart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/shopping_cart_btn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/shopping_cart_toolbar"
            tools:listitem="@layout/shopping_cart_list_item" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/shopping_cart_btn"
            layout="@layout/child_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_shopping_cart"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**EDIT**

> I don't want the height to be 124dp but rather to be 0.15 of the entire available height in which the layout is included in

Now you want the `Toolbar` to be **17%** of the parent layout while it's not a direct child of it.. that looks strange and not matching with `ConstraintLayout` guidance as the Toolbar is not a direct child of the parent's `ConstraintLayout`

So, you can't constraint the `Toolbar` to the parent `ConstraintLayout`; instead you can constraint the entire child layout to the parent layout.. So you need to limit the height of the entire child layout by either by hard-coding it or by constraining it. And without constraining the height you'll get the layout disappear as in your shared picture.

In top answer I had constraint it to the bottom of the `RecyclerView` and this is what you already did in your shared `RecyclerView` constraints with `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/shopping_cart_btn"`. This may not be perfect as we can't predect the height of the `RecyclerView` at compile time.

So, here is another option of constraining the height of the child layout relative to the parent layout using `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` constraint likewise you did with its `Toolbar` but with a percentage that is greater than the 17%. It's up to you to pick a suitable percentage, here I will pick 50%.

Now the height of the parent is 100%. The height of the child is 50%, and as you need the `Toolbar` height to be 17% of the parent, then now double it to be 34%. And you have to change it according to your picked value of the entire child layout.

Now the parent layout will be

Parent layout:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".framework.ui.view.fragments.shop.ShoppingCartFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/shopping_cart_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/color_primary"
            app:title="@string/bottom_nav_shopping_cart"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_shopping_cart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/shopping_cart_toolbar"
            tools:listitem="@layout/shopping_cart_list_item" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/shopping_cart_btn"
            layout="@layout/child_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Child layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"> <!-- Changing this to wrap_content makes weird stuff -->

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.34"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.17"
```

belongs to `parent_layout`, should be set for `<include` tag or at least for `ConstraintLayout` placed in `child_layout` (root view in file)

Comment: But how exactly am I able to style my child_layout then? When I set `    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"` to my toolbar and inside the include_tag, it looks very weird. I can't set it to my constraintlayout of the child_layout because there will be other views as well inside the constraintlayout